# How to generate a list of lambdas in scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to make a procedure which takes a list of lambdas, and uses the return value of these lambdas. In order to create and populate this list, I made the procedure:

```
(define generate-list-of-numbers-lambdas 
  (lambda (function) 
    (if (= (function) 3)
        (list (lambda () 2))
        (cons (lambda () (- (function) 1)) 
              (generate-list-of-numbers (lambda () (- (function) 1)))))))
```

This procedure takes a procedure as an argument, and generates a list of numbers from the return value of the argument procedure until `2` (IE the original argument is a procedure which returns `20`, the generate-list-of-numbers makes a list `(19 18 17... 3 2)`

This procedure takes a procedure as an argument (the argument procedure has no arguments, itself, and just returns an integer), however, this `generate-list-of-numbers-lambdas` procedures generates a list, but only the first element is a lambda.

Comment: Study your recursive call closely.

Comment: I get an error when I try to use it. The recursive call has an incorrect name, `generate-list-of-numbers` should be `generate-list-of-numbers-lambdas`. I guess you're not getting an error because you also have a procedure with that name that returns numbers instead of lambdas.

Comment: If you fix that typo it works fine.

Comment: This question is confusing. If you're really trying to make a procedure that takes a "list of lambdas", why is its argument a single function that is called to obtain its return value?  When we say "a function takes", that refers to the argument values that go in.

Comment: "... and uses the return value of these lambdas". In what way? To calculate what return value or produce what output?

Comment: Determining a clear statement of the detailed requirements is more than half the battle. Lisp or Scheme code will often just pop out from that as a rephrasing of the requirements. If you can specify it, you can code it; and not before.  When you become a good coder, you can then use code as a specification tool. You don't initially know what the specification is, but you can investigate the possibilities using code as a way of discussing it with yourself or colleagues or the machine. Where the code ends up becomes the spec. That is "exploratory programming".

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure works just fine if you recur using `generate-list-of-numbers-lambdas` instead of `generate-list-of-numbers`; you simply forgot the `-lambas` part of the name.

A couple more things though. Your procedure calls `(function)` 3 times in the body. If the result needs to be used in more than one place, you should use a `let` binding.

```
(define generate-list-of-numbers
  (lambda (function)
    (let ((x (function))) ;; bind `x` to `(function)`
      (if (= x 3) ;; use x
          (list (lambda () 2))
          (cons (lambda () (- x 1)) ;; use x
                (generate-list-of-numbers (lambda () (- x 1)))))))) ;; use x
```

Next we see `(lambda () ...)` littered all about the code. A tiny dose of data abstraction goes a long way here -

```
(define num
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda () x)))

(define generate-list-of-numbers
  (lambda (function)
    (let ((x (function)))
      (if (= x 3)
          (list (num 2)) ;; use num
          (cons (num (- x 1)) ;; use num
                (generate-list-of-numbers (num (- x 1)))))))) ;; use num

;; calling our procedure is nicer too
(generate-list-of-numbers (num 20))
```

We see `(num (- x 1))` twice again. It should be a `let` binding.

```
(define generate-list-of-numbers
  (lambda (function)
    (let ((x (function)))
      (if (= x 3)
          (list (num 2))
          (let ((next (num (- x 1)))) ;; bind `next`
            (cons next (generate-list-of-numbers next)))))) ;; use `next` twice
```

We used `num` to put numbers into our container. We will use `val` to take numbers out.

```
(define val
  (lambda (n)
    (n)))

(map val (generate-list-of-numbers (num 20)))
;; '(19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2)
```

Going back, we see we can use `val` in our procedure too. Lastly, we rename `function` to `n`. This allows us to think purely in terms of our numbers and forget that the values are wrapped a function ([thunk](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._thunk%29%29)), or some other data container.

```
(define generate-list-of-numbers
  (lambda (n) ;; `function` renamed to `n`
    (let ((x (val n))) ;; use `val` to read value of `n`
      (if (= x 3)
          (list (num 2))
          (let ((next (num (- x 1))))
            (cons next (generate-list-of-numbers next)))))))

(map val (generate-list-of-numbers (num 20)))
;; '(19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2)
```

All of that said, this is a weird procedure. I can only guess it is a homework assignment or something. It almost seems like you're trying to implement a lazy list of numbers, but it's not quite right. Starting the list at `n - 1` and ending at `2` is another obscure choice and red flag. If you can provide a broader goal, I may be able to update the answer and provide additional help.